# Extract field id in Vaadin json response by JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter, vaadin

Currently I'm trying to extract field id from Vaadin json response to detect all comboboxes (RTFComboBox) and process them further. Example response (cut down):

```
for(;;);[{
    "syncId": 113,
    "clientId": 113,
    "changes": [],
    "state": {
        "1273": {
            "caption": "",
            "styles": ["tokenfield", "tokentextfield"]
        },
        "1274": {
            "styles": ["RTFTokenField"]
        },
        "1275": {
            "width": "185.0px",
            "immediate": true,
            "styles": ["RTFTokenField", "RTFComboBox", "tiny"],
            "registeredEventListeners": ["focus"]
        }
    }
}]
```

What I need is to get id number (here 1275), I can deal with "for(;;)" junk but I can't extract proper id values. I was trying to use Regex Extractor but this solution isn't very flexible (or I just can't write proper expression).

Any ideas how to get parent id when styles child array contains 'RTFComboBox'? Maybe here is required some more complex solution, like some script in groovy, than JMeter's JSON Extractor?

Answer (score 0):

I would advice, to write a groovy script in the beanshell processor, parse the JSON and then get all the keys for the state object. Here's the code snippet, please make sure you add the java-json.jar in the JMETER_HOME/lib folder

```
    try {

        String jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
        JSONArray jsonArray =  new JSONArray(jsonString);
        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject states = object.getJSONObject("state");
        String keys[] = states.getNames(states);

        for(int i=0; i< keys.length; i++) {
            log.info(keys[i]);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've finally made it using JsonSlurper, this is my JSR223 PostProcessor script:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def response = jsonSlurper.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString().drop(8))
//drop to remove for(;;); junk preventing proper parse
def map = [:]
response.state[0].each {k, v -> if(v.styles != null && v.styles.contains("RTFComboBox")) {map.put(k, v)}}
//map contains key (field id-most important to me) and key (rest of values in node)
```

If you need some specific value, just in map.put line set v.field, i.e.:

> map.put(k, v.immediate)